# The 'K' key on my laptop keyboard is bound to F3 on both Windows and Ubuntu. Why does this happen, and how do I fix this?

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Title says it all.

I discovered this in Chrome trying to type in a URL and the search bar kept popping up. I checked in notepad and gedit and it brings up a search prompt in those programs as well.

This only happens with the laptop keyboard, not my USB keyboard. Any advice is appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is almost certainly a hardware problem.  You will need to contact the manufacturer of the computer to have the keyboard replaced.

Comment: This is what I feared, but I wanted to get a second opinion. Thanks for the response

Comment: @NickAberle, keep in mind that if you experience a problem like this again that occurs independently of the operating system and software, it is likely to be a hardware issue.  I'd test it with a live CD and possibly in the BIOS to confirm.

Comment: Strangely enough, it is working again. I didn't do anything to attempt to fix it

Comment: @NickAberle, it's possible that the keyboard circuitry is compromised.  If the problem reappears, send it in.  I'm glad it's working now.